# What does a pseudocode for Breadth First Search with adjacency matrix look like?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

Hi I am trying to have a general idea of how to implement BFS with matrix, however most examples/resources I found online are using adjacency lists.

Can someone provice me a pseudocode for it？

Comment: You mean graph is stored in matrix?

Comment: just replace traversing throught the list with something like 
for i <- 1 to V if ((a[q[v][i] > 0) && (!b[i])) { add i to q }